# How to create timeseriesgraph for multiple exposures and events in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, timeserieschart

I want to create a time-line graph (with ggplot function?) in R for 276 cases separately but displayed in one figure. They are exposed to different treatments for different times and can have multiple events. I want to mark exposure to different treatments by using colors and mark events during these treatment strategies in this graph (e.g. with dots).

[my data look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwmpn.png)

Does someone know (partly) how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not in what is called '[Tidy format](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf)'. You first want to do some data wrangling to get your data from 'broad' to 'long' format before you get to plotting your data. Your different treatments should be in a single column (called treatments) instead of multiple columns. I suggest you look into the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages  (see this [cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf)).

To put your treatments into rows rather than columns you could use the `gather` function from the `tidyr` package. Once this is done you could create a ggplot similar to:

```
ggplot(your_data, aes(x = time_of_event, y = value, colour = treatment)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Thank you Jeroen! Your post really helped be.